# Google App engine PHP post back problem

Tags: php, google-app-engine, post

i have uploaded a `php` web application to **google app engine** , but all the `POST` back pages are open as a *'save as'* without post backing the data ! ..

any one has a solution for this ?  or a alternative for `POST` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google app engine runs applications written in Python or Java, not PHP. You could work around it using Quercus (PHP runtime written in Java)

Comment: It compiles PHP pages successfully using Quercus : more info :www.caucho.com/resin-3.0/quercus/

Comment: do i need to change any thing in the code to match with Quercus ?

Comment: You might. Have you looked at this page: http://blog.caucho.com/2009/04/28/quercus-on-the-google-app-engine/

Comment: isnt `POST` is a HTML action which is no connection with PHP ?

Comment: Yes, but if you are getting PHP pages back as "save as", then its likely that the pages are not getting compiled as PHP. If you open the response page? Do you see the PHP source code in the page?

Comment: when i acess with the direct link php pages are views successfully ! .. that means its compiled r8 ?

Comment: I would check two things. 1. Make sure that the php pages dont have any php tags hidden in the source. If they do, they are not getting compiled. 2. Check the content type header of the page that you are posting to. If its not text/html, it may cause the browser to perceive it as another file type and ask you to save it.